# Looking for a cartoon that has a giant grey robot

Tags: story-identification, robots, cartoon

I'm looking for a cartoon probably from 1980s to 2000s that has a giant grey robot. The robot is controlled by 5 people, 1 in each of its hands, 1 in each of its feet, and 1 in its body or maybe the head. It has antenna on the head. The robot is nothing fancy, just your typical normal robot look.

Please help... I was searching the whole night to find this show

Comment: So it doesn't form from a bunch of different robots, just controlled by five different people?

Comment: Could it be [Voltron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltron)?

Comment: Moblie suit gundam? (it would help if you could remeber wether the show was a western cartoon or an anime, might narrow it down a bit)

Comment: Definitely sounds like voltron.

Comment: @Naib Voltron is anything _but_ grey ...

Comment: @Ifurini depends if grey was the key remembered part. I doubt it